# Making a Haskell function to work with infinite list

Tags: haskell

I would like to know how I can turn a function to work with infinite list?

For example, I have a function to revert a list of lists.

`innerReverse [[1,2,3]]` will return `[[3,2,1]]`. However, when I tried  `take 10 $ innerReverse [[1..]]` It basically runs into an infinite loop.

When I do `innerReverse [(take 10 [1..])]` It gives the result: `[[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]`

Comment: So you want to reverse an infinite list? You need to wait then.

Comment: @zerkms sorry. What do you mean? There is no way?

Comment: Well, please put what you expect to see as a result for `reverse [1..]` call. Btw, your first pattern match should accept an empty list and return an empty list. That way you avoid duplication.

Comment: @zerkms I have updated the with expected result. But I think I see your point when I tried to do so...so this is impossible I guess?

Comment: Your expected result is not correct. `take 10` returns the first 10 elements of a list. For the reversed `[1..]` it will be `[∞, ∞ - 1, ∞ - 2, ...]`

Comment: @zerkms um...if I have a f = a . b. c Do I need all a b and c to work with infinite list for f to be able to wok with infinite list?

Comment: No you don't, but when you performed `take 1 (reverse [1..])` you ask haskell to materialize the whole infinite list. Your expected result is not correct, please go through comments once again. To see why your expected result is wrong - try to pass `[1..99999]` which is not infinite but big enough for you to see the actual result. Then change the upper bound to `999999` and compare results.

Comment: right...I tried innerReverse [(take 10 [1..])] and it gives the expected result

Comment: Now replace 10 with something else. Sorry, I cannot repeat the same thing more than 3 times. :-(

Comment: `innerReverse [(take 10 [1..])]` --- is a compltetely different call. Which is identical to `innerReverse [[1..10]]`, so it has nothing to do with infinite lists in your function (since your function now accepts a finite materialized list)

Comment: @xcoder What do you expect `innerReverse [[1..]]` to print?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is a *lazy* language, which means that evaluations are only performed right before the result is actually used. That's what makes it possible for Haskell to have infinite lists; only the portions of the list that you're accessed so far are actually stored in memory.

The concept of an infinite list makes what you're trying to do impossible. In the list `[1..]` the first element is `1`. What's the last element? The answer is that that's a trick question; there is no concept of the "end" of an infinite list. Similarly, what is the first element of the reverse of `[1..]`? Again, it's a trick question. The last element is `1`, but the list would have no beginning.

The reverse of `[1..]` is not `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`. The reverse of the latter is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, not `[1..]`.

Comment: “There is no concept of the "end" of an infinite list” – indeed that would be a complete oxymoron.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it depends on what you call infinite. [As an example.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist-0.8/docs/Data-FMList.html) There is no concept of the "end" of an endless list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's one of the differences between Haskell and set theory; a mathematician would think of `[0..]` as ω and `[0..]++[0..]` as 2ω. But Haskell can't distinguish them.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure I understand your example. Are you using `++` as an analogue to the union operation?

Comment: @JustinLardinois, I'm pretending it's transfinite ordinal addition :-)